# Replace an array values between the two indexes using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have an arrays which is like ,

```
[2200,0,0,200 ,200 ..... 100]
```

Now, Here , I am trying to replace the values using the indexes .

I want to replace the values between index  `1 to 15 by 100`. .
So, and store it in a same array.

can any one help me with this ?

Comment: `I want to replace the values between index 1 to 15 by 100. . So, and store it in a same array`. What does this mean? You want to replace them _with_ 100 or _adding_ 100 or _subtracting_ 100? Also, by index `1`, do you mean the first, or second element? Remember arrays (and in your case, a `list`), are 0-based.

Comment: `arr[1:15] = 100` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
arr = np.array([2200,0,0,200 ,200 ..... 100])
arr[1:15] = 100
```